# is there any other way to post data?

Tags: python, django

while submitting my data i am having error saying please check you detail even though all the data i have input is correct

def register(request):
registered = False

```
user_form = UserForm()
user_profile_form = UserProfileForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(data = request.POST)
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(data = request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and user_profile_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        user_profile_form.save(commit = false)
        user_profile_form.user = user #creating that OneToOneField relation

        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            user_profile_form.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

        user_profile_form.save()
        registered = True
        return index(request)


    else:
        print('Error occured while Posting Data please check you detail!')

else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm()

return render(request,'levelfive_second_app/register.html',context = {'user_form':user_form , 'user_profile_form':user_profile_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your forms are not valid, you can see the errors in {{form.errors}}